# Switching to mobile theme while cache is enabled

Tags: theming, mobile-tools

I have a Drupal7 website using a modified Zen subtheme that looks ugly on mobile devices and i want some kind of utility to create a separate mobile theme .
I tried to use differents modules like Mobile Switch,Mobile Detect ,Mobile Tools & Theme Key but unfortunatley they don't support Drupal Default Cache .
Is there any way or method or another module to resolve this problem.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

ThemeKey does support the Drupal cache.

However, the Drupal cache cannot perform device specific cacheing on a single domain since page caches are organized by absolute URLs. See this discussion for an explanation: https://www.drupal.org/node/2242303

The solution is to have a device redirect at the server level to a mobile subdomain (ie. m.mysite.com) which shares the same docroot and switches the theme there. The Boost module is recommended and the process is outlined here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1214890